# js: special char in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

in my regular expression, I tried to remove all "{" and "}"s from a string.
Pushing the script with packer/minimizer scripts, breaks them.
That's why I'd like to know about a better and more compatible way of writing:
`mystring.replace(/\{/g,"");`?

Comment: What do you mean by "more compatible"? The regex you used is compatible with all modern browsers.

Comment: I think @ledy is looking for something that won't break his/her sub-par packer. I would guess that the curly-brace is being treated as a javascript special character rather than part of the regex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading the question, it sounds like you've found a bug with the minifier/packer. My first suggestion would be to use a better minimizer that doesn't have these issues, but if you're stuck with what you're using, you could try using the [unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-unicode-escape) in the regular expression:

```
mystring.replace(/\u007b/g, '');
```

Alternatively, you could try [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
mystring.split('{').join('');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a string instead of a regex. I'm not sure if this is "better" but it should not break when minified. If you provide the minified example, we may be able to help with that.

```
mystring.replace("}", "").replace("{", "");
```

**Edit:**

If the curly bracket is causing the problem, perhaps this would work...

```
var reg = new RegExp("\\{|\\}", "g");
mystring.replace(reg, "");
```

Example from the console...

```
> var mystring = "test{foo}bar{baz}";
> var reg = new RegExp("\\{|\\}", "g");
> mystring.replace(reg, "");
 "testfoobarbaz"
```

Lastly, you could do this:

If a regex really wont work for you, this will replace all `{`'s and `}`'s
It is probably a horrible solution, considering performance, but...

```
mystring.split("}").join("").split("{").join("");
```

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: regex is more efficient, this is a good solution for 1 or 2 characters.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `'\'` characters so that the string evaluates to `'\{'` rather than `'{'`: `"\\{|\\}"`

Comment: @zzzzBov this is not needed, as far as I know. Could it be browser dependent? From a few simple tests, you don't seem to need to escape any characters. It appears that the browser is escaping them for you...

Comment: @Kyle, in a string literal `'\{'` turns into `'{'`, which makes your regular expression evaluate to `'{|}'`. In this case, it happens to separate the `{` characters, however if the pattern desired was to match `{0}`, you'd have an invalid regular expression. To prevent unwanted errors, its best to consistently escape special characters, hence my recommendation to use double `\ ` characters.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
mystring.replace(/\u007B/g,"");
```

This uses unicode rather than the actual symbol, so your packer won't get confused. If you want to replace more than one character in a single statement, you can use the "or" pipe:

```
mystring.replace(/\u007B|\u007D/g,"");
```

`{` = `\u007B`
`}` = `\u007D`

For more unicode codes see:
http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf